# Printing a term using custom formatter

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

On a custom template for a taxonomy view, I want to render the current term (the one being viewed) using my custom taxonomy term formatter, how do I do that?

I have looked at the `field_view_field` function, but it's not clear to me how I would use its parameters `field_view_field($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $display = array(), $langcode = NULL)` - esp. the `$field_name` part is not clear. I am afraid this is not the right function... Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want apply specific display formatter to some field like taxonomy terms, the best way is to write a display formatter module, and apply it to your entity_type via display setting on specific view mode, so if you want do this completely programmatically you need:

1. write display formatter moule
2. define view mode if necessary (e.g. for node we have `full`, `teaser` and ...)
3. add configuration to field instance setting

if you need some sample code to write display formatter module, let me know...

EDIT: if you want pass field instance setting to `field_view_field` you have something like this:

```
$display = array(
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'colorbox',
    'settings' => array(
        'colorbox_node_style' => 'simpledeal_company_medium',
    ),
);
field_view_field($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $display, $langcode = NULL);
```

this example code is about colorbox display formatter, should be replaced by yours

to do above via admin you should go to vocabulary display setting `admin/structure/taxonomy/VOCAB_NAME/display`, in `CUSTOM DISPLAY SETTINGS` check `Taxonomy term page` and set your display formatter, in this way you may do not need to change taxonomy-term.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks, actually step 1 is fully completed. I have my module working brilliatly on nodes and within views. I just don't know how I could invoke it in a taxonomy-term.tpl file, so it gets the $term object and renders the output. Is that what you mean by step 3? Care to elaborate?

Comment: exactly, you have two options, set field instance setting via admin interface `admin/structure/taxonomy/VOCAB_NAME/display` or pass setting as array to `field_view_field` all is around `$display` parameter

Comment: `field_view_field` looked tempting to me as well, the problem is that in the tpl file for a taxonomy term, I don't have a field really. I would have to pass something like `$self` or `$term` to the function, instead of `$field_name`. I think I will make a helper function in my module, so that I can call it directly, passing $term as parameter.

Comment: display formatter apply just on fields, taxonomy terms are  entity_type, vocabularies are bundles and terms in vocabularies are entity. if you have fields attached to your bundles, so you know their names. something like field_image...

Comment: Yep, you're right, sometimes it's good to return to the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper module like [Custom Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters). Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows users to easily create custom CCK/Field Formatters without the need to write a custom module. Custom Formatters can then be exported as CTools Exportables/Features or Drupal API Formatters.